# Unit Test ViewModel Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, repository, tdd, viewmodel

I am doing TDD and I just want to verify that particular repository method is called when executing viewmodel method.

```
class SignInViewModel{
  CustomerRepository customerRepository;
  public void get(){
    customerRepository.getCustomer();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding anything you tried. If you know the basics of JUnit you could easily do this verification.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/21855/mockito-verify check this out.

Comment: @Test
    public void get() {
        signInViewModel.get();
        Mockito.verify(customerRepository.getCustomer());
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject the repository instance through viewmodel constructor. 
After that mock the repository instance in your test class and verify if you call the get() method, repository's getCustomer() is called.

Comment: @Inject
    public SignInViewModel(@NonNull CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        super();
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    } did this and in test ne

Comment: did this and in test @Mock CustomerRepository customerRepository; SignInViewModel signInViewModel = new SIgnViewModel(customerRepository); got nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test 
public void get() { 
   signInViewModel.get(); 
   Mockito.verify(customerRepository).getCustomer(); 
}
```

customerRepository should be a mock.

If you need more details I would suggest you to check this out

https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/addedittask/AddEditTaskViewModelTest.java

Mockito verify is used in the above TestSample. You can also see how a repository is mocked. If you are getting a NPE probably you have not mocked your repository or you did not create your viewModel in your test. If you are still not clear I would recommend you to do get to the basics of Junit and Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to inject the CustomerRepository on the constructor of the viewModel like this:

```
class SignInViewModel{

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public SignInViewModel(CustomerRepository customerRepository){
       this.customerRepository = customerRepository ;
    }

    public void get(){
        customerRepository.getCustomer();
    }
 }
```

and in your test file you can mock the repository as well :

```
@Test 
public void get() { 
    CustomerRepository mocked = new Mockk<CustomerRepository)()
    SignInViewModel signInViewModel = new SignInViewModel(mocked)
    signInViewModel.get(); 
    Mockito.verify(customerRepository).getCustomer();
}
```